# Take user input from the background

Tags: linux, input, process, background

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have a process running in background from a Linux terminal which takes user input and does things according to that input even if the terminal window is not focused, so I can work with other GUI applications, and then when I push some pre-defined buttons, something might alter the program's state without loosing the focus of my current window. Just as simple as that (not that simple for me though).

I don't ask for an specific kind of implementation. I'm fine with anything that may work: C, C++, Java, Linux Bash script... The only requisite is that it works under Linux.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Well you can have your server read a FIFO or a unix domain socket (or even a message queue).  Then write a client that takes command line input and writes it to the pipe/queue from some other terminal session.  With FIFOs you can just echo input from the command line itself to the pipe but FIFOs come with their own headaches.  The "push the button and magic happens" is a lot trickier but maybe that was badly phrased?